# isInConsole() Showing False in embedded VF Page

Tags: visualforce, consoleintegrationtoolkit, service-console

Long Story short no matter what i do i cannot make this salesforce method work. Please help me shine some light on what i am doing wrong so i can work on creating subtabs from an Account page inside of my service console.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" >   
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/39.0/connection.js"/> 
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/39.0/apex.js"/> 
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/39.0/integration.js"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testIsInConsole() {
            if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) 
                alert('in console');
            else 
                alert('not in console');
         }
    </script>

    <apex:commandButton oncomplete="testIsInConsole()"   value="Click here 
    to check if the page is in the Service Cloud console"/>
</apex:page>
```

[image: View from Console]

Comment: I was just looking at you answering someone else on a similar issue. This page is embedded into the account page layout, at a high level i am overriding the default contact related list with  my own custom related list since. 
Will this help me at all? 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145016/sforce-console-isinconsole-not-working-returns-false-even-in-console
@santanuboral

Comment: yes, I have answered this earlier

Comment: I can see that, but going deeper if the default IsInConsole does not work, how will i find the primaryTabId, in order to make a subtab. Is your solution not a work around?

Comment: how are you opening this visualforce page? is that page opening on PrimaryTab?

Comment: I added an image above, the visual force page is embedded into the primary tab. right now i can create other primary tabs, but cannot create subtabs. I am assuming i cannot create subtabs because my visualforce page does not believe i am inside of the console to get the primary tabs id

Comment: if you are opening the standard record from listview in console then page will be in console and you can easily get primary tab id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are opening the standard record from listview in console then page will be in console.

It works perfectly based on your code.

[image: page in console]

Issue is: Your development mode is opened.

> **Close the development mode option and it will work perfectly.**

Comment: That was exactly the issue. developer mode open caused the issue.

Comment: Just for some extra flavor to this answer: turning on development mode will cause your VF Page to become nested. The development mode creates an iframe and the VF page is a second iframe inside of that one. The console toolkit has some limitations around nested frames and this is one of them. It "looks up" to see where it is, and instead of seeing the console it sees the development mode frame and decides it's not in the console after all. 

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_best_practices.htm

Comment: Nice explanations